# GitHub NuGet API request blocked by CORS because of Authorization header

Tags: http, cors, nuget, github-api

I am developing a VS Code extension that needs to query various NuGet API's including private ones. I want to allow the user to provide an Authorization header that I will use to call these private API's.

I am having issues with the GitHub NuGet API because the browser is making a preflight OPTIONS request to the API to check for CORS. I know this is intended and normal when you include an Authorization header.
My issue is that the GitHub API does not return a "access-control-allow-headers: authorization" header. So the Browser is blocking my request, as I think it should.

Am I missing something here or is the GitHub API improperly implemented?
Any help, ideas are greatly appreciated.

The code that is making these requests can be seen [here on Github.](https://github.com/adrian-pavel/visual-nuget/blob/7952ffc4a923e3be49107d1e95b45c3c11e611af/src/app/services/nuget-api.service.ts#L242)
Or just the request part here:

```
this.http
  .get<ApiIndexResponse>(sourceUrl, {
    headers: requestHeaders,
  }) // where requestHeaders is a normal "Bearer token" header, so nothing special
```

**Screenshot of failing preflight request:**
[image: Failing preflight request]

**Example of working request to the AzureDevOps API:**
[image]